# Deserialize json into C# object for class which has default private constructor

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I need to deserialize json for following class.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Property { get; set; }

    private Test()
    {
        //NOTHING TO INITIALIZE
    }

    public Test(string prop)
    {
        Property = prop;
    }
}
```

I can create an instance of Test like

```
var instance = new Test("Instance");
```

considering my json something like

```
"{  "Property":"Instance" }"
```

How shall I create an object of Test class as my default constructor is private and I am getting object where **Property is NULL**

I am using Newtonsoft Json parser.

Comment: what library are you using? how do you get an instance of `Test`?

Comment: If there isn't any factory which generates a `Test` object, how do you expect to deserialize a JSON into an instance of it?

Answer (score 47):

You can make Json.Net call the private constructor by marking it with a `[JsonConstructor]` attribute:

```
[JsonConstructor]
private Test()
{
    //NOTHING TO INITIALIZE
}
```

Note that the serializer will still use the public setters to populate the object after calling the constructor.

---

Another possible option is to use the `ConstructorHandling` setting:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};

Test t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json, settings);
```

Comment: The second option is the best if the object you want to serialize is in a library/assembly where you do not want to introduces 3rd party dependencies (including dependencies to Json.Net...)

Comment: How can serializer call private constructor? Am I missing something, or is `JsonConstructor` for specifying which constructor to call when deserializing (for a class that has multiple public constructors), instead of being able to magically call private constructors?

Comment: `[JsonConstructor]` tells Json.Net which constructor to use when deserializing that class.  The serializer can call a private constructor because it uses [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) internally.  With reflection it is possible to call private methods.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem like you need to take any extra steps.

Using Json.NET v6.0.8, the following C# program works inside LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{   
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"Property\":\"Instance\"}");

    Debug.Assert(o.Property == "Instance",
        "Property value not set when deserializing.");
}

public class Test
{
    public string Property { get; set; }

    private Test()
    {
    }

    public Test(string propertyValue)
    {
        Property = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Example of a bit modified example online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qFumV

Comment: Note that in this example, the public constructor with the `propertyValue` parameter is not being used. Instead, the private constructor is being used alongside the `Property` `set`ter. See my answer to this question if you're trying to get this to work with `get` only properties.

Comment: this is not working with text.json. I guess this is newton json

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a Serializer setting and give assign ConstructorHandling here. Please remember to define the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to the private constructor.
I have similar case with abstract BaseNode.cs and its concrete ComputerNode.cs implementation. You can create the classes, copy/paste the code below and do some experiment.

```
    public abstract class BaseNode
{
    [JsonConstructor] // ctor used when Json Deserializing
    protected BaseNode(string Owner, string Name, string Identifier)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Identifier = Identifier;
    }

    // ctor called by concrete class.
    protected BaseNode(string [] specifications)
    {
        if (specifications == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (specifications.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        Name = specifications[0];
        Identifier = specifications[1];

    }

    public string Name{ get; protected set; }
    public string Identifier { get; protected set; }

}


public class ComputerNode: BaseNode
{
    public string Owner { get; private set; }

    [JsonConstructor] // not visible while creating object from outside and only used during Json Deserialization.
    private ComputerNode(string Owner, string Name, string Identifier):base(Owner, Name, Identifier)
    {
        this.Owner = Owner;
    }

    public ComputerNode(string[] specifications):base(specifications)
    {
        Owner = specifications[2];
    }
}
```

For JSon Read and Write  following code helps -

```
    public class Operation<T>
{
    public string path;

    public Operation()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "nodes.txt");

        if (File.Exists(path) == false)
        {
            using (File.Create(path))
            {
            }
        }
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void Write(string path, List<T> nodes)
    {
        var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes, Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText(path, ser);
    }

    public List<T> Read(string path)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(path);

        var res =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(text);
        return res;
    }

}
```

**All the best!**

Answer (score 1):

Today the short answer is: Rename the constructor parameter `prop` to `property` and your code will work fine.

```cs
public class Test
{
    public string Property { get; }

    public Test(string property)
    {
        Property = property;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new Test("Instance")));
```

Newtonsoft.Json supports initializing properties using constructor parameters out of the box, without needing to set any additional attributes or changing any settings. The only constraint is that the parameter name needs to be a case insensitive match to the property name.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered today that having a **public** constructor *that takes parameters* and no ***declared*** unparameterized constructor causes NewtonSoft to attempt to call the public constructor, the only one that it can find, since there is no explicit default constructor, and it cannot apparently find and call the default constructor provided by the framework *unless* it is ***the only constructor***.

Explicitly declaring a default constructor causes NewtonSoft to call the correct (unparameterized) constructor.