# Initializing object data in the constructor by deserializing a json file

Tags: c#, json, object, constructor

Ok so I want to get rid of the first constructor, and be able to deserialize directly. Is there a way to just pull each variable from the json one at a time? Or is there a blanket statement I could use to pull them all at once and populate the object.

```
 public MasterEmailSettings()
 {
      _user = "";
      _password = "";
      _domain = "";
      _emailAddress = "";
 }
 public MasterEmailSettings(string path)
 {
      var tempObject = new MasterEmailSettings();

      try
      {
           tempObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path));
           _domain = tempObject.Domain;
           _password = tempObject.Password;
           _user = tempObject.User;
           _emailAddress = tempObject.EmailAddress;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this ctor? Maybe you are able to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path))` to get an instance of this object?

Comment: I've always just done something like `MasterEmailSettings myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path));` and as long as the JSON object was serialized from the type that I want to deserialize it to, I don't have any problems.

Comment: the only reason is i dont want to have to type out the try/catch every time I create a new object from the json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't create a constructor that is going to be responsible for going out to disk, reading in a file, using a 3rd party lib to deserialize to the object, to then just take bits of the deserialized object and put into certain fields on the class. Normally, a constructor conveys simply object initialization, and this instead is wrapping up a lot of responsibility into the constructor that I'm not sure you need to do anyway.

One suggestion I have if you really want to encapsulate this logic into a space on this class is create a factory method. A factory method indicates more broadly that there is actual work to be done in order to initialize a type:

```
public static MasterEmailSettings Create(string path){
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path))
}
```

I'm not entirely sure on the use case for the original constructor where the code sets a tempObject to the deserialized form of the object only to set a few fields from it? We'd need a little more information on that.

Again, you would probably be better off just using...

```
var emailSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path))
```

...in your code wherever you're wanting this feature, but if you'd like to encapsulate it a bit, the factory method above would be a good path to go down.

*** Update ***
I've read in a comment you don't want to place a try/catch around whenever you want to load this information from disk and that makes sense. The factory method above + try catch logic where you catch an IOException explicitly would be a good impl.

```
public static MasterEmailSettings Create(string path){
    try{
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path))
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        //Answer how the system should respond in the event that the file did not exist. Maybe you just want to log it and throw?
        throw; //Do not use throw ex as it will re-start the stack trace from the point the exception is thrown. Use either throw or throw new SomeException("", ex); to make sure the original stack trace on the exception is preserved.
    }
}
```

There are some other exceptions ReadAllText can throw, you may want to consider them and how your code should respond to them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can not set all properties in constructor in one step.

You can use `[JsonConstructor]` with your constructor: [Deserialize json into C# object for class which has default private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243738/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-object-for-class-which-has-default-private-constru)

Answer (score 1):

I'd split it up a little differently.  I agree with the earlier answer about removing the file reading from the object and just as a static method that does the deserialization

```
public class MasterEmailSettings
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public static MasterEmailSettings Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(json);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this in your code

```
MasterEmailSettings.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText("<some path>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
public class MasterEmailSettings
{
    private static MasterEmailSettings _settings;
    public string User { get; }
    public string Domain { get; }
    public string Password { get; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; }

    private MasterEmailSettings()
    {
        this.User = "user";
        this.Password = "pw";
        this.Domain = "domain";
        this.EmailAddress = "foo@bar.com";
    }

    public static MasterEmailSettings Load(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            _settings = new MasterEmailSettings();
            Save(path);
            return _settings;
        }

        var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        _settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterEmailSettings>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        return _settings;
    }

    private static void Save(string path)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_settings, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }
}
```

then just call it like that

```
var settings = MasterEmailSettings.Load("yourpath");
```