# Deserialization reference cycle don't bring the data into constructor

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I have the following scenario (Newtonsoft.Json):

```
public class SubElement
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public SubElement(string name, Element parent)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(name));
        }

        Name = name;
        Parent = parent ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));
    }
    public string Name { get;private set; }
    public Element Parent { get; }
}

[JsonObject(IsReference =true)]
public class Element
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Element(string name, IList<SubElement> subelements)
    {
        Name = name;
        Subelements = subelements;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<SubElement> Subelements { get; }
}

Element element = new Element("test", new List<SubElement>());
element.Subelements.Add(new SubElement("first", element));
element.Subelements.Add(new SubElement("second", element));
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
Element deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Element>(serialized);
```

On deserialization process, **SubElement** constructor get ivoked with parent **Element** as being null, although, in the serialized data it is stored properly. I used [JsonObject(IsReference =true)] attribute in order to manage circular referencing but it seems it isn't enough for deserialization to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to serialize/deserialize tree-like structure, containing reference to parent.

I believe the problem is that when `[JsonConstructor]` is called for children, the parent is not yet constructed. This however doesn't matter if you just deserialize properties (we will need parameterless constructor in this case):

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Element
{
    [JsonProperty] // required for private setter
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public IList<SubElement> Ports { get; private set; }

    [JsonConstructor] // required for private constructor
    Element() { }

    ... // your public constructors (not used for serialization)
}

public class SubElement
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Element Parent { get; private set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    SubElement() { }

    ...
}
```

I've tried to keep your architecture. References used: [deserialize private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25950112/1997232), [deserialize private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24243738/1997232).

The json looks same:

> {"$id":"1","Name":"test","Ports":[{"Name":"first","Parent":{"$ref":"1"}},{"Name":"second","Parent":{"$ref":"1"}}]}

Comment: I've tried with [JsonProperty] before, but I didn't have any Setter accessor (at least private) in order to reflection to work. Thank you!

Comment: with sources ... i like you.

Comment: Another question, how to combine this kind of tree structure with abstract classes. I mean when you have a base class (here can be **Element** class) and others derived from the base. For that case you have to define a custom JsonConverter and use some data (maybe an enum) from each derived class to know to which type to convert the data. The problem is when this convertor is called for reference values, for which representation looks like '{"$ref":"1"}' and the convertor can't obtain any info. Any ideas?