# How to set up constructors for deserialization of Get only properties without having to duplicate code in c#?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

The problem is described by means of an example.

I have an abstract base class `Box`,

```
    abstract class Box
    {
        public Box(double panelThickness) : 
            this(IDGenerator.GetNewID(), panelThickness)
        { }

        protected Box(int id, double panelThickness)
        {
            ID = id;
            PanelThickness = panelThickness;
        }

        public int ID { get; }
        public double PanelThickness { get; }
    }
```

an inherited class `RectangularBox`

```
    class RectangularBox : Box
    {
        private static double _rectPanelThickness = 0.2;

        public RectangularBox(double xDimension, double yDimension) : 
            base(_rectPanelThickness)
        {
            // ---- Code duplication:
            XDimension = xDimension;
            YDimension = yDimension;
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        private RectangularBox(int id, double xDimension, double yDimension) : 
            base (id, _rectPanelThickness)
        {
            // ---- Code duplication:
            XDimension = xDimension;
            YDimension = yDimension;
        }

        public double XDimension { get; }
        public double YDimension { get; }
    }
```

and a simple `IDGenerator`:

```
    static class IDGenerator
    {
        private static int _id = 0;

        internal static int GetNewID()
        {
            _id++;
            return _id;
        }
    }
```

An example can be run by means of this test method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;    
[TestMethod]
    public void BoxJsonDeserializationTest()
    {
        RectangularBox rectangularBox1 = new RectangularBox(8, 9);

        JsonSerializerSettings serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
        };

        string boxJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
            (rectangularBox1, Formatting.Indented, serializationSettings);

        var rectangularBoxFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RectangularBox>
            (boxJsonString, serializationSettings);
    }
```

Instantiating an object of `RectangularBox` causes an ID to be generated in the base class and the `XDimension` and `YDimension` properties to be assigned in the public constructor of the sub-class.  Two things to note here:

1. Both `XDimension` and `YDimension` are Get only properties.  Hence, its only assignable in the constructor.
2. The user should not be able to generate an ID by input.  This is prohibited by having a Get only ID property in the base class.  If the public constructor of `RectangularBox` is used, a new ID is generated automatically.  However, upon deserializing `RectangularBox` from JSON and having a protected constructor in the base class called by the private constructor in the child class allowing the ID property to be set when deserializing from JSON (using Newtonsoft.Json.

When serializing this object to JSON and then deserializing at a later stage, a new `ID` should not be generated for the object, but instead the `ID` property be assigned from the JSON.  Similarly, the `XDimension` and `YDimension` properties must also come from the JSON.  Hence the reason for the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute over the private constructor of `RectangularBox`.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to get rid of the code duplication in both constructors of `RectangularBox`, but still maintain the ability to deserialize the Get only properties from a JSON.  The properties could have private setters and marked with `[JsonProperty]` attributes, which would allow the properties assignments to be removed from the constructors into a separate method, but this is not desired.  The user should not be allowed to change those properties once a `RectangularBox` object is created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not easy (until C# 9). A common approach to dealing with this is to create one set of types for your serialization, and one set of types for your business logic. This usually also solves the problems of having a slightly different format in the serialized output than the business logic types allow.

Comment: In C# 9 you can set property setters as `init`, which means they will be available in initialization expressions but also *reflection*, which deserialization uses.

Comment: Note that your code as posted is not correct, because private json constructor calls `base (id)`, while parent constructor being called is actually `public Box(double panelThickness)`. Should be `base(id, _rectPanelThickness)` I guess.

Comment: Can you not use a private constructor that is only called from the JSON deserializer?  Like in this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243738/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-object-for-class-which-has-default-private-constru

Comment: @Evk.  Thanks.  You are correct.  I corrected the code sample above.

Comment: Can someone explain why we can't just refactor the duplicate code into a new private method and call it from the two existing constructors?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Comment: @ Rich N.  You cannot do this, since the properties only have Get methods which, in C#, indicates to the compiler that the private member of this property is readonly.  Readonly properties can only be set in the constructor.  If the property had any sort of Set method (private, protected or public), your suggestion would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `id` argument nullable:

```
abstract class Box
{
    public Box(double panelThickness) : this(null, panelThickness) { }

    protected Box(int? id, double panelThickness)
    {
        ID = id ?? IDGenerator.GetNewID();
        PanelThickness = panelThickness;
    }

    public int ID { get; }
    public double PanelThickness { get; }
}

class RectangularBox : Box
{
    private static double _rectPanelThickness = 0.2;

    public RectangularBox(double xDimension, double yDimension)
        : this(null, xDimension, yDimension) { }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private RectangularBox(int? id, double xDimension, double yDimension)
        : base(id, _rectPanelThickness)
    {
        XDimension = xDimension;
        YDimension = yDimension;
    }

    public double XDimension { get; }
    public double YDimension { get; }
}
```

Obviously if your JSON does not contain an `id` then a new id will be generated, but that seems like something within your control.

Comment: @ Johnathan Barclay.  Thanks.  It's been a while, but eventually, I used this solution, originally thinking it would be a simpler refactoring compared to the solution provided by @Evk, which would also work perfectly.  I later realized that the refactoring for both solutions would take a similar amount of time.  I would have liked to mark both answers as correct, but alas can only mark one.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, you can split your get-only property into property and readonly field (bascially what compiler does for you when you use `SomeProperty {get;}`), and then do this:

```
abstract class Box
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(ID))]
    private readonly int _id;
    [JsonProperty(nameof(PanelThickness))]
    private readonly double _panelThickness;
    protected Box(double panelThickness)
    {
        _id = IDGenerator.GetNewID();
        _panelThickness = panelThickness;
    }

    protected Box()
    {
        // default contstructor for deserialization
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ID => _id;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double PanelThickness => _panelThickness;
}

class RectangularBox : Box
{
    private static double _rectPanelThickness = 0.2;
    [JsonProperty(nameof(XDimension))]
    private readonly double _xDimension;
    [JsonProperty(nameof(YDimension))]
    private readonly double _yDimension;

    public RectangularBox(double xDimension, double yDimension) :
        base(_rectPanelThickness)
    {
        _xDimension = xDimension;
        _yDimension = yDimension;
    }

    protected RectangularBox()
    {
        // default contstructor for deserialization
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public double XDimension => _xDimension;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double YDimension => _yDimension;
}
```

It works because JSON.NET can set readonly fields no problem, but when you use autogenerated readonly property - it has no idea about corresponding readonly field, all it sees is just a property which has no setter and so no means to set it's value. Here we tell it explicitly which field to use.

Whether it's "better" than code duplication in constructor is arguable, but at least achieves your desired result (properties are still readonly, no code duplication in constructors".

EDIT: I noticed that C# 7.3 introduced a feature - you can mark an autogenerated property with `[field: AttributeHere]` annotation and it will apply that attribute to autogenerated field. BUT, autogenerated field has `CompilerGenerated` attribute, so it will be ignored by default by JSON.NET. However, there is a setting to change that, this setting is on `ContractResolver`, for example:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() {
        SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers = true
    }
};
```

Then you might not split your readonly property, and instead mark it with attributes, if you are using compiler for C# 7.3+:

```
abstract class Box
{
    protected Box(double panelThickness)
    {
        ID = IDGenerator.GetNewID();
        PanelThickness = panelThickness;
    }

    protected Box()
    {
        // default contstructor for deserialization
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [field: JsonProperty(nameof(ID))]
    public int ID { get; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [field: JsonProperty(nameof(PanelThickness))]
    public double PanelThickness { get; }
}

class RectangularBox : Box
{
    private static double _rectPanelThickness = 0.2;

    public RectangularBox(double xDimension, double yDimension) :
        base(_rectPanelThickness)
    {
        XDimension = xDimension;
        YDimension = yDimension;
    }

    protected RectangularBox()
    {
        // default contstructor for deserialization
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [field: JsonProperty(nameof(XDimension))]
    public double XDimension { get; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [field: JsonProperty(nameof(YDimension))]
    public double YDimension { get; }
}
```